# How to access Hasura metadata programmatically?

Tags: graphql, hasura, hasura-docker

I am new to Hasura GraphQL. I have this problem that I am trying to solve.

I want to fetch all the hasura role and all the columns from all the tables. I earlier thought there will be some command that I can use to get these information but I am facing difficulties to find one.

I am going to use this information to create automation script. to update my GitHub repo. but not able to find a way to get these information, not sure if this is my lack of knowledge or documentation for hasura does not cover this part.

I did find hasura_metadata table on internet but I am not able to access it. FYI, I am using hasura 2.12.1

Answer (score 0):

you can use the metadata api for getting information about the hasura metadata:
https://hasura.io/docs/latest/api-reference/metadata-api/index/